# 404 Not Found for react.js nginx and docker compose

Tags: nginx, http-status-code-404

I'm relatively new to the whole field, I have this error by nginx logs

> GET /auth/signin HTTP/2.0" 404 153 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:120.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/120.0" "-"

My nginx.conf

```nginx
 server {
    listen 80;
    server_name dev.site.pl www.dev.site.pl;

    location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
        allow all;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location / {
        rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
    }

 }

 server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    server_name dev.site.pl www.dev.site.pl;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/dev.site.pl/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/dev.site.pl/privkey.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://site-fe:80;
        
        proxy_set_header    Host                $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto   $scheme;

        gzip on;
        gzip_min_length 1000;
        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/xml;
        
    }

    location /api {
       proxy_pass http://be:8080;
       
       proxy_set_header    Host                $host;
       proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto   $scheme;

    }
    
  }
```

I tried to find answers on this forum, but they all led to either a complete failure of the site, or I received a new error when going to https://dev.site.pl/auth/signin (namely 500 and 304)

Comment: Do you expect the `/auth/signin` URL to return some other status? If so, why? What makes you think it's a valid URL?

Comment: @Phil Because the site is working, and the sign in button too, when clicked, a window pops up, but if you reload the site at this moment or paste it into the search bar, a 404 error appears

Comment: Sounds like you're using client-side routing and haven't set up the appropriate server-side URL handling. Can't say more without knowing what the apps are behind your nginx proxy, in particular `site-fe`

Comment: @Phil What do I need to provide for you to understand the problem further?